# Extract 2 groups(lists) of N number of cards each out of a 52 card deck

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im working on this card game and in the below code Im trying to extrat 2 groups of N number of cards out of the 52 card deck. The first list is the "known cards" for the player and they should be the first N cards from shuffled the deck, then the second list of cards are the "unknown" ones, they should be the same amount of N.

```
def shuffle_deck():
    shuffled_list = random.sample(create_deck(), 52)
    return shuffled_list

def draw_card(N, card_list):
    list_N = []
       for i in range(N):
           extract = card_list.pop(0)
           list_N.append(extract)
       return tuple([list_N, card_list])
print(draw_card(2, shuffled_list()))
```

With the Above code Im getting the 2 lists like this:

```
([<__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D520>, <__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D040>], [<__main__.Cartas object at 0x0352DFE8>, <__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D340>... and so on until the card object #52])
```

how can I make the second list to be the same size/lenght as "N"?
For example if N = 4
the the result should be 2 lists of 4 cards each:

```
   ([<__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D520>, <__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D040>, <__main__.Cartas object at 0x0352DFE8>, <__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D340>], [<__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D520>, <__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D040>, <__main__.Cartas object at 0x0352DFE8>, <__main__.Cartas object at 0x0364D340>])
```

Comment: Repeat the code you have for "list_N" with another variable name.

Comment: I'd also suggest implementing __repr__ or str so the debug output is more readable.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelButscher :)

Answer (score 0):

I just did what  Michael Butscher suggested, repeated code for another empty list and works fine now:

```
def draw_card(N, card_list):
    list_N = []
    list2_N = []

    for i in range(N):
        extract = card_list.pop(0)
        list_N.append(extract)

    for i in range(N):
        extract2 = card_list.pop(0)
        list2_N.append(extract2)
    return tuple([list2_N, card_list])
print(draw_card(2, shuffled_list()))
```